# Inkscape causing tool paths to be doubled/duplicated

Tags: inkscape, svg

I just got my hands on a pen plotter today and have been experimenting with using Inkscape to generate gcode from an SVG graphic. The graphic is a bunch of lines generated by a Processing 3 sketch.

The problem I'm having is that the generated gcode causes each line to be traced twice, in the same direction. Here's an example:

```
(Start cutting path id: line800912)
(Change tool to Default tool)

G00 Z17.200000
G00 X103.550637 Y204.448157

G01 Z13.200000 F2000.0(Penetrate)
G01 X104.362603 Y191.466608 Z13.200000 F2000.000000
G00 Z17.200000

(End cutting path id: line800912)


(Start cutting path id: line800912)
(Change tool to Default tool)

G00 Z17.200000
G00 X103.550637 Y204.448157

G01 Z13.200000 F2000.0(Penetrate)
G01 X104.362603 Y191.466608 Z13.200000 F2000.000000
G00 Z17.200000

(End cutting path id: line800912)
```

I noticed that the path id is identical in these two passes, which seems weird...

Using Inkscape 1.0, my workflow is:

- Drag .svg into Inkscape
- Resize canvas/object
- Convert to path via Path > Object to Path
- Add orientation points via Extenions > Gcodetools > Orientation Points
- Create tool paths via Extensions > Gcodetools > Path to Gcode

I've experimented with changing the stroke width which doesn't help. I also tried using Stroke to Path instead of Object to Path, which creates an outline of the line instead of a single line but also doubles the tool path.

Worth noting that this also happens if I draw a shape using Inkscape's built in tools instead of importing an SVG. I'm guessing this is something silly that I don't understand, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I actually found a solution on an Inkscape forum post here: https://inkscape.org/forums/cutplot/path-to-gcode-duplicate-lines-wrong-number-of-passes-workaround/

This appears to be a bug in Inkscape 1.0 caused by using Python 3 instead of Python 2, although my system version of Python is 2.7... oh well.

Anyway, the solution is to set "Cutting order" to **Pass by Pass** in the Path to Gcode dialogue box. I had it originally set to the default value, Subpath by Subpath.

The generated gcode looks fine now!